# incompatible types when a function returns a union

Tags: c

here is code pieces:

ip.h

```
typedef union _ip_t{
    struct _dot_ip {
        unsigned char f4;
        unsigned char f3;
        unsigned char f2;
        unsigned char f1;   //the first field
    }dot_ip;
    unsigned int int_ip;
}ip_t;
```

ip.c

```
ip_t
get_mask(int sub_len)
{
    assert(sub_len > 0 || sub_len < 32);
    ip_t ret;
    ret.int_ip = ~((1 << (32 - sub_len)) - 1);
    return ret;
}
```

main.c

```
ip_t mask;
mask = get_mask(24);
```

then the error:

> error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘ip_t’ from type ‘int’
>
> mask = get_mask(24);

I can't figure out where is wrong, any help will be appreciated

PS: gcc verison: gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2

Comment: No problem here http://ideone.com/hrcOCE

Comment: Note that identifiers starting with an underscore character are reserved for the implementation and should not be used in your own code.

Comment: thanks for remainding @5gon12eder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No declaration of your your function is visible in `main.c`. In `main.c` the function is completely unknown to the compiler. Your compiler assumed that it returns `int`. The rest follows.

Such behavior of the compiler is C89/90-specific. It has been outlawed in C99 language specification. Modern C compilers are not supposed to let you call undeclared functions.

Add a prototype of your `get_mask` function to `ip.h`

```
ip_t get_mask(int sub_len);
```

to tell the compiler that `get_mask` actually returns `ip_t`.

Since your are using `gcc`, I suspect that the compiler actually issued an additional diagnostic message informing you about `get_mask` being undeclared. Did you just ignore that message?