# string is not tokenized properly

Tags: c, strtok, atoi

I am applying one formula over ip address. but it gives me some random output sometimes, which is weired. sometimes it does not tokenize properly, and sometimes it gives 0 value. Ratio of error regenaration is almost 2-5 in a 1000 sample.
calling function = formula(IPADDRESS);
which I am calling with hundreds of different IPs per second.

```
 int formula ( char ip[]){

            char *token = NULL;
            unsigned long value;
            int finalv;
            char ipaddress[16];
            char delims[]=".";        
            int octet=3;
            value = 0;
            FILE *fp;
            fp = fopen(LOGFILE, "a");
            strcpy(ipaddress,ip);
            fprintf(fp, "%s\n",ipaddress);
            token = strtok( ipaddress,delims);

            while( token != NULL ) {
               fprintf(fp,"%d",(atoi(token));
               if ( atoi(token) != 0 ){
                    if(octet ==3)
                            value = value + (255 * 255 * 255 * (atoi(token)));
                    else if(octet ==2)
                            value = value + (255 * 255 * (atoi(token)));
                    else if(octet ==1)
                            value = value + (255 * (atoi(token)));
                    else if(octet ==0)
                            value = value + (atoi(token));
               }
                    octet--;
               token = strtok( NULL,delims);
            }

            finalv = value % 9999;

            fprintf(fp, " -- %d \n",(int)finalv);
            if(fp)
                    fclose(fp);
            return (int)v;
    }
```

OUTPUTFILE :
(I have Given only false outputs)

```
172.17.82.255
 172  0  1  -- 1983
--
172.254.254.254
 172  0  0  0  -- 1728
--
172.255.255.225
 172  0  -- 1728
--
172.255.255.255
 172  21  0  1  -- 7390
--
172.255.84.255
 172  0  8  -- 3768
```

Comment: `token = strtok( NULL,token )` will try to find the next token in `ipaddress` using the previous token as delimiter...? I don't think that's intentional.

Comment: I apologize , I have paste wrong code.Here is the updated code, Still I'm getting errors.

Comment: Why are you multiplying by 255 powers...??? The next byte position corresponds to weight 256.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of looping over `strtok()`, the

```
int a=0, b=0, c=0, d=0 ;
int value ;
sscanf( ip, "%d.%d.%d.%d", &a, &b, &c, &d );
value = ( ( a * 255 + b ) * 255 + c ) * 255 + d ;
finalv = value % 9999
```

should, I think, give you the same answers. (Although as pointed out in the comments, the `255`s may be meant to be `256`).

Comment: Shouldn't you rather multiply by 256...?

Comment: I could claim that I was just checking whether anyone was reading properly :-)

Comment: Although `255` is what the OP was using... either that's wrong, or (since they're modding with `9999`), it may be some kind of hash function?

Comment: Same 'error' in original question, I suppose you just copied the constant from there. :) Hash function? Possibly...

Answer (score 2):

You're redeclaring `token`:

```
        char *token = NULL;  // <-- here
        unsigned long value;
        int finalv;
        char ipaddress[16];
        char token[]=".";    // <-- and here
```

Later in the code, then, you have some confusion about which `token` is supposed to be used in which context. That is particularly obvious here:

```
token = strtok( NULL,token);
```

...where the first token is presumably meant to be the pointer and the second the array.

I'm a bit surprised that that even compiled, mind you, but does your compiler not at least warn you about that?

EDIT: In the "updated" code,

```
fp = fopen(LOGFILE, token);
```

is executed when `token` is `NULL`, which leads to undefined behavior. Did you mean

```
fp = fopen(LOGFILE, "w");
```

?

Comment: Nice, didn't catch the redeclaration. That explains the dodgy second `strtok()` call.

Comment: I apologize , I have paste wrong code.Here is the updated code, Still I'm getting same errors.

Answer (score 0):

change

`token = strtok( NULL,token);`

to

`token = strtok(NULL,".");`

PS: Because you call this function hundreds of times per second, you'd better open and close the file outside the function

Comment: I apologize , I have paste wrong code.Here is the updated code, In which I am getting errors. I will move open and close file outside the function.

Comment: why not use this trick ,it is much simple than yours @user95711 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27915245/incompatible-types-when-a-function-returns-a-union